# The minimum diameter of a sphere such that a cone may balance on it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

There is a solid sphere of diameter D, with a right circular cone placed on top of it. The cone has a height h and the diameter of the cone base is d, and d=h. Explain why the minimum value of D (diameter of sphere) must be d=h in order that the cone may still be balanced?

I have attempted using moment of inertia for this question and then realised I may be better off using moments/torque, to see how the normal force changes with a changing diameter of sphere. I used the centre of the sphere as the centre of rotation, and based my work off the centre of mass being in the cone. Looking at other examples and explanations of torque and moments  I could not figure out how to solve this particular problem in this manner.

I also looked into calculating the restoring force for the cone but could not find any guidance regarding this that was not directly to do with pendulums.

Any ideas on different methods of solving this would be welcome as well as anything which may be useful for the techniques I have tried to use.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Surely this isn't a solid cone, right? It is a hollow cone, and connects to the sphere not at the top point but on a lower circle. The distribution of mass of the sphere is proportional to the surface area, so the surface above the circle of contact versus the surface below the circle of contact has something to do with stability.

If the sphere is on a table, if it is too small then the cone can't rest on it at all. Unfortunate that this is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**  Think about the potential energy $U(\theta)$ of the cone when the contact point is at the top of the sphere ($\theta = 0$) vs. when the contact point is at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical.  If the cone is stable when $\theta = 0$, what can you say about the potential energy function $U(\theta)$ at that point?